# How can I filter for blank fields in Jira?

Tags: jira

I'm trying to create a filter in Jira. I want to pull out all issues where a certain custom field is blank. Any ideas?

E.g. is there some logical operator plus wildcard that I can enter e.g. <>%.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not in 3.x - check out the issue @ atlassian JRA-7909
(I would post hyperlinks, but I'm too new on this site and I'm allowed only one).

Version 4 has JQL, an advanced query language: Search on Advanced Searching on the Atlassian site.

The release of 4.0 of JIRA is real soon now :-).
Actually the Atlassian JIRA site is running the latest version, so you can already investigate how this advanced search works.

Francis

Answer (score 4):

you may use "is empty" like this:

`duedate is empty AND status in (Open, "In Progress", "Awaiting info")`